# how to update chartjs2 option (scale.tick.max)

Tags: chart.js

I have a Bar Chart with this Option

```
     scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            display:false,
            beginAtZero:true,
            max: 1150
          }
        }]
      }
```

now i change the values of my only dataset

```
      barChartData.datasets[0].data = newData;
```

and update the chart

```
      window.myBar.update();
```

How can i also update the max scale of the yAxes??

I have to use a max scale so i cant use suggestedMax.

Answer (score 13):

found the Solution myself.

to change any options of the chart:

```
myBar.config.options
```

in my case

```
myBar.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = newValue
```

after this you have to call

```
window.myBar.update();
```

Comment: Very frustrating, their documentation talks in detail about each option, but gives little help as to the context of where each goes in initial object, and how to change dynamically,

Comment: @Josh Diehl using a Js debuger to breakpoint on some variable, this help a lot to see the internal architecture of every Chart?

Comment: Had the same issue, but now I see it only adds in a new tick to the top of the yAxis. I expected it to re-calculate the yAxis ticks with the fixed amount of ticks based on the `max`. You could also do it like: `myBar.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = newValue`.

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution for Line Chart.

You can use '**beforeFit**' callback function that you can find here in the docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

1. In **scale.chart.config.data.datasets** you have the chart dataset
2. You must set the **scale.options.ticks.max**

Example:

```
scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          beforeFit: function (scale) {

            // See what you can set in scale parameter
            console.log(scale)

            // Find max value in your dataset
            let maxValue = 0
            if (scale.chart.config && scale.chart.config.data && scale.chart.config.data.datasets) {
              scale.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
                if (dataset && dataset.data) {
                  dataset.data.forEach(value => {
                    if (value > maxValue) {
                      maxValue = value
                    }
                  })
                }
              })
            }

            // After, set max option !!!
            scale.options.ticks.max = maxValue
          }
        }
```

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Setting max on the scale passed to this event worked for me after setting max on my chart options didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html has pretty up to date information. 
the keey is to recognise what the chart object is. :)
I struggled for half a day reading various pages until i found the right way

1. use the baseChartDirective to access the chart directly by doing this -> this.chart
2. To update scales do this:

> ```
>  var barChartOptions =  {
>       legend: { display: true },
>       scales: { yAxes: [{ id: 'yaxis', type: 'linear', position: 'left', ticks: { min: 0, max: maxScale } }]}  };  
>  this.chart.chart.options = barChartOptions;
> ```

3. then update the chart:

> this.chart.chart.update();

you can pretty much update everything. Just need to realise what the chart object means in this page: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html
:)