# Set height of chart directly

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How can I manipulate of chart height directly?

Not the whole canvas height but only curves?
For example 20% of canvas height

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do this is by using an [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) and fix the size of the legend at for example 80% of the canvas, the remaining space should then be filled with the chart.

Comment: Try This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004611/how-to-update-chartjs2-option-scale-tick-max

Comment: Is any working example with setting legend area?