# Chart JS axes extension

Tags: php, graph, chart.js

I have some Chartjs charts on my webpage, they are dynamically generated.
It works, but on max levels are at the very top of the chart.
Ideally for e.g. the first chart the axes would go up to 60 and on the second one to 8.

Is there a setting so the lines will keep a certain distance from the top of the grid?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `yAxes.ticks.max`, the user defined maximum value for the scale, which overrides the maximum value from `data`.

> For further information, please consult [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip#tick-configuration) from Chart.js documentation.

For your first chart, this would look as follows:

```
options: { 
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        max: 60
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would require a fixed "max" value. The data is is dynamically, sometimes the higest value is 10, the other time it is highest is 1000.

Comment: @eGuard: If your data is dynamically changing, you could compute and update `ticks.max` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021260/2358409)